# From $B \cdot A \cdot x=B \cdot y$ to $A \cdot x=y$

Tags: linear-algebra

A and B are matrices. x and y are column vectors.

\begin{align*}B \cdot A \cdot x=B \cdot y\tag{1}\end{align*}

When we can get (2) from (1)?

\begin{align*}A \cdot x=y\tag{2}\end{align*}

Comment: In general, if $B$ is invertible.

Comment: More generally, if $B$ has a left inverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as 
\begin{align}
B(Ax-y)=0
\end{align}
There are two possibilities (assuming $B\neq 0$), either $q=Ax-y$ lies in the null space of $B$, or $Ax=y$ or both. If $B$ if full rank (invertible), then $Ax=y$ is the only possibility.

Comment: $Ax=y$ implies that $Ax-y$ lies in the null space of $B$, so these 2 possibilities reduce to 1.

Comment: did you mean that if $Ax=y$, then $Ax-y=0$ which already lies in null space of $B$?

Comment: dineshdileep: Yes, $Ax=y$ implies $Ax-y=0$ is the reason that these 2 possibilities are actually 1.